# Restart D3 bar chart animation

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, charts, restart

I am working on a widget that shows several `D3` bar charts with different values, one after the other, in a sliding carousel.

When the page loads, the bar chart animate as it should, but when the page goes on to the next chart - whether it be on click or by itself - I would like it to restart the animation again each time. 
I have tried calling `animateChart()` in the console but this doesn't work.

I am looking for a function that I can call from the console or from another function, like `animateChart()`, that will reload the `D3` bar chart animation.

Here is a link to my widget:

http://jsfiddle.net/alocdk/oa5tg1qu/1/

Comment: Can you please paste the code here instead of referring to a link ? Or reproduce in a jsbin.

Comment: Yes of course, here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/alocdk/oa5tg1qu/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where you could enhance your `animateChart` function.

In fact you were modifying only data that were **enterring** your graph.

By calling :

```
d3.select(svg)
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(data)
        .enter().append("rect")
[...]
```

Everything following this, will only apply on the new data.

You may want to read these to understand the pattern to follow with data update in D3.

- [General Update Pattern, I](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218)
- [General Update Pattern, II](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221)
- [General Update Pattern, III](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234)

Here is my shot now http://jsfiddle.net/uknynmqa/1/

I've removed the loop you were doing on all your svg, because I assumed you wanted to only animate the current one.

And your function is updating all of the data, and not only those enterring thanks to :

```
// Update the data for all
var join = d3.select(svg)
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(data);

// Append new data.
join.enter().append("rect")      
    .attr("class", function (d, i) {
        var low = ""
        i == minIndex ? low = " low" : "";
        return "bar" + " " + "index_" + i + low;
    })

// Update everyone.
join.attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return barWidth * i + barSpace * i;
    })
    .attr("y", chartHeight)
    .attr("height", 0)
    .transition()
    .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 100;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return chartHeight - y(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function (d) {
        return y(d);
    });
```

D3 is following a really specific data update pattern.

Depending on what you want to do, you can follow this. It's up to you what you want to animate or not.

```
// Link data to your graph and get the join
var join = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data);

// Update data already there
join.attr('x', 0);

// Append the new data
join.enter().append('rect')
    .attr('x', 0);

// Remove exiting elements not linked to any data anymore
join.exit().remove();

// Update all resulting elements
join.attr('x', 0);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was hoping to achieve. I definitely have a lot to learn, thanks for the Update Pattern links. 
Have an awesome day :)

Comment: ha ha, no problem at all... I've learned about it too this week :D It's changed my life since.